# Mouse Events for lat/lon locations without using PushPins in Bing Maps AJAX?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bing-maps

I work for a fleet tracking company and Bing maps as a whole slows down to an unusable speed when we put all our pushpins that represent service calls on the map. We theorize that it has to do with the number of DOM elements it has to move when you drag the map. We might have dozens of vehicles and hundreds of service calls on the map at once.

To get around this, I'm creating a custom `TileLayer` who's source goes to our server and there tiles are constructed to have our pushpins display on the tiles. So far so good except that now I don't know how to do `MouseOver` events for the "pushpins" that are on the tiles.

I'm looking for a way to raise Mouse events on certain locations on the map without adding DOM elements.

A sure-fire, but probably incredibly slow way, to do it would be to have a `MouseOver` event on the entire map object that'll see which service calls the mouse is close to. If the mouse is close enough, it could call an event that way. I really want to avoid doing this.

I have tried adding PushPins with a defined height/width and without icons in hopes of having an easy to move element (one that doesn't need to be redrawn) that could fire mouse events, but to no avail. No events fire.

Comment: I tried 5000 pushpins with icons on the interactive SDK, the performance was not very good but still usable on my machine.  Are your custom pushpins just pushpins with icons or html content pushpins.  Is bing maps continually trying to get the pushpin icon image every time the view changes?  You can also try pushpin clustering.

Comment: Since the pins might move (our service calls being relocated to new lat/lon), we update them every 10 seconds. We're using a clustering module and every time we call it's `setData` it clears the old data and adds the new data. This constant removal and re-addition of pins bringing IE to a crawl is something we've brought up to Microsoft before and they still haven't fixed it. They're just pushpins with icons. Also the biggest performance drop we're looking to improve is on IE. Chrome of course handles it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider.

1: Should you display that much information on such a small map? I mean, best practices in web mapping recommend to keep readibility in the best way so clustering might be an interesting option but most of all maybe the use case scenario should be reconsidered to display only interactive pushpins after selecting one vehicle or person in tracking scenario.

If you have to use clustering, this should be done using server-side clustering so you only have to download what you're capable of display on the map control and it will reduce the amount of data that will need to be downloaded, will optimize performances on client-side (only smaller amount of elements that needs to be managed).

2: If you want to create a tile layer that means you're using bitmap information and not vector information. There might be some approach for you:

- Use the map click and get the coordinates corresponding to your click (pixel -> geo) and call a web service to get the complete information about the event or element that should be displayed on specific area
- Use the map click but rather than using a web service, operate on the client side. Adding to this, you could be using Canvas element to draw your pushpin or information on the map control so you can keep the interaction and be able to customize the rendering based on client-side event or operations. This is not officialy supported but it can work pretty well depending on your use case.

The limitations on the number of elements is mostly related to the browser and not the Bing Maps platform, if you try the same things in IE8 with other mapping control, you will have the same bad experience that is directly linked to your use case.